# Convert dataframe with start and end date to daily data

Tags: pandas, date, time-series

I have one record per ID with start date and end date

```
id  age state   start_date  end_date
123 18  CA     2/17/2019    5/4/2019
223 24  AZ     1/17/2019    3/4/2019
```

I want to create a record for each day between the start and end day, so I can join daily activity data to it. The target output would look something like this

```
id  age state   start_date
123 18  CA      2/17/2019
123 18  CA      2/18/2019
123 18  CA      2/19/2019
123 18  CA      2/20/2019
123 18  CA      2/21/2019
            …
123 18  CA      5/2/2019
123 18  CA      5/3/2019
123 18  CA      5/4/2019
```

And of course do this for all ids and their respective start dates in the dataset.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit**: I had to revisit this problem in a project, and looks like using [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) is almost 3x faster:

```
df["date"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: pd.date_range(row["start_date"], row["end_date"]),
    axis=1
)
df = (
    df.explode("date", ignore_index=True)
    .drop(columns=["start_date", "end_date"])
)
```

**Output**

```
      id  age state       date
0    123   18    CA 2019-02-17
1    123   18    CA 2019-02-18
2    123   18    CA 2019-02-19
3    123   18    CA 2019-02-20
4    123   18    CA 2019-02-21
..   ...  ...   ...        ...
119  223   24    AZ 2019-02-28
120  223   24    AZ 2019-03-01
121  223   24    AZ 2019-03-02
122  223   24    AZ 2019-03-03
123  223   24    AZ 2019-03-04

[124 rows x 4 columns]
```

### Original answer:

#### `melt`, `GroupBy`, `resample` & `ffill`

First we [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) (unpivot) your two date columns to one. Then we [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) on day basis:

```
melt = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'age', 'state'], value_name='date').drop('variable', axis=1)
melt['date'] = pd.to_datetime(melt['date'])

melt = melt.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('d').first())\
           .ffill()\
           .reset_index(level=1)\
           .reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
          date     id   age state
0   2019-02-17  123.0  18.0    CA
1   2019-02-18  123.0  18.0    CA
2   2019-02-19  123.0  18.0    CA
3   2019-02-20  123.0  18.0    CA
4   2019-02-21  123.0  18.0    CA
..         ...    ...   ...   ...
119 2019-02-28  223.0  24.0    AZ
120 2019-03-01  223.0  24.0    AZ
121 2019-03-02  223.0  24.0    AZ
122 2019-03-03  223.0  24.0    AZ
123 2019-03-04  223.0  24.0    AZ

[124 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: If you don't want to do the changes in-place, you can use `.assign()` like so: `df.assign(date=df.apply(...)).explode("date", ...).drop(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Use listcomp and `pd.date_range` on values of  columns `start_date` and `end_date` to create list of date for each rec. Next, construct a new dataframe from result of listcomp and join back to the other 3 columns of `df`. Finally, `set_index`, `stack` and `reset_index` back

```
a = [pd.date_range(*r, freq='D') for r in df[['start_date', 'end_date']].values]
(df[['id', 'age', 'state']]
    .join(pd.DataFrame(a)).set_index(['id', 'age', 'state'])
    .stack().droplevel(-1).reset_index()
    )

Out[187]:
      id  age state          0
0    123   18    CA 2019-02-17
1    123   18    CA 2019-02-18
2    123   18    CA 2019-02-19
3    123   18    CA 2019-02-20
4    123   18    CA 2019-02-21
..   ...  ...   ...        ...
119  223   24    AZ 2019-02-28
120  223   24    AZ 2019-03-01
121  223   24    AZ 2019-03-02
122  223   24    AZ 2019-03-03
123  223   24    AZ 2019-03-04

[124 rows x 4 columns]
```